# Pinia + TS: type of store as an argument to a function

Tags: typescript, pinia

I have several different pinia stores that share a bunch of functions. For example

```
const storeOne = defineStore('a', () => {
    const foo = () => alert('store a');
    const bar = () => alert('bar');
    const a = ref(null);
    return {
        foo,
        bar,
        a
    }
});

const storeTwo = defineStore('b', () => {
    const foo = () => alert('store b');
    const foobar = () => alert('foobar');
    const b = ref(null);
    return {
        foo,
        foobar,
        b
    }
})
```

both stores will have a function `foo` in this case. The rest can basically be ignored in that scenario, it's just an example.

I have a function that needs to call `foo()` and I would like to pass a store in that function but I don't know how I could type this properly. My current attempts for example were:

```
type StoreCollection = ReturnType<typeof storeTwo| typeof storeOne>
type PickedStoreCollection = Pick<StoreCollection, 'foo'>
const callStoreFunction = (store: PickedStoreCollection) => {
    store.foo(); // works great -> this will know the correct store
}

callStoreFunction(storeOne); // TS error: types a incompatible
callStoreFunction(storeTwo); // TS error: types a incompatible
```

I made a basic example here https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/relaxed-scooby-ubncqg?file=%2Fsrc%2Fmain.ts%3A20%2C1 in the main.ts file

I know I could easily cast every call like this to

```
callStoreFunction(storeTwo as unknown as PickedStoreCollection);
```

But I would really like to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the store creation

`defineStore` resurns not a `store: Store`, but a `useStore: () => Store`

```
callStoreFunction(storeOne())
// or renamed
const storeTwo = useStoreTwo();
callStoreFunction(storeTwo)
```

Comment: omg... thats embarrassing. I tried that so long and it never worked in my real code, so I created that minimal example and for whatever reason missed the most obvious thing... thank you very much.